# unbind event from custom function

Tags: jquery

I use custom function:

```
function youtubeload() {
      $(".youtube").each(function() {
        $(document).on('click', '#' + this.id, function() {
          ...
        }); 
      }); 
};
```

I call this function like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {youtubeload();});
```

After colorbox ajax popup I call the function again so it can be used on newly loaded elements like so:

```
//cbox_complete is colorobox event hook    
$(document).bind('cbox_complete', function(){
    youtubeload();
    });
```

Now, after modal window is closed, I have a **problem with duplicate** triggers (after clicking, the function is triggered twice.) I tried to unbind the click event like so:

```
//cbox_closed is colorbox event hook
    $(document).bind('cbox_closed', function() {
    $(document).unbind('click');
    });
```

But it is not working. How can I unbind the event, so there are no duplicate triggers? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(document).unbind('click')` would unbind all click events on all elements. You just need to unbind on the element which triggered the event. Use `$(this)` to target that element. This would solve the issue with unbind.

```
$(document).bind('cbox_closed', function() {
    $(this).unbind('click');
    });
```

But with this you would need to bind the click event again to that element.

To avoid all the hassels, just use `.on` event to delegate the click handler to the dynamically created elements.

```
$(document).on("click",'cbox_complete', function(){
    youtubeload();
 });
```